# Transfer different AWS log files to Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash-grok

I am trying to transfer different log files from **AWS** to **Elasticsearch** and I am unable to do that. I have looked on how to use **logstash**, create **JSON** files, making the input, output and **grok** in the file. But I am unable to transfer different files from Amazon AWS.

Comment: What do you mean by AWS ? Do you mean AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: I am looking to transfer log from S3, EC2 and different services to elasticsearch.

Comment: Please make your question clear what are the exact resources of AWS you are using and what logs you want to to transfer from where to where.

Comment: I am trying to transfer EC2 and S3 logs to Elasticsearch so that I can analyse them on Kibana

Comment: Did you follow this guide https://www.import.io/post/analysing-elb-elastic-load-balancer-logs-with-logstash-and-kibana/

Comment: Yeah! Thanks It helped a little.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this guide for the transfer to work properly

https://www.import.io/post/analysing-elb-elastic-load-balancer-logs-with-logstash-and-kibana/